# javascript inheritance reports no fun

Tags: javascript

I defined a javascript inheritance function and try to inherit a class

```
function extends(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.uber = Parent.prototype;
}



function MyClass (){



};

MyClass.prototype.doSomeThing=function(){


};
```

Then I wrote

```
    var a={};
    extends( a  , MyClass  );
    a.doSomeThing();
```

but it reports a.doSomeThing is not a function

Welcome any comment

Comment: `a` must be a constructor function as well, not a simple object. Look at the implementation of `extend`, you have `Child.prototype = new F();` in there.

Comment: JavaScript has no classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable A is an object, not a constructor / function, so a.doSomething is not a function but a.prototype.doSomething is.

Turn a into a function or loose the Child.prototype = .. to get it to work.